# How to prevent Entity Framework from updating a certain column if it's not null?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a table with a column called InsertedBy. Basically when the record is inserted the first time the column holds the name of the person who inserted it. Then it never gets modified with any future updates to that row. The column is a property in the C# entity because it's needed to be read along with the rest of the columns.

How do I prevent EF from updating this column after the first insert? I am using SaveChanges in the dbContext.

Comment: It won't unless you make a change to the value after you retrieve it (*assumption is it is being tracked*). To prevent a change you can change the visibility of the setter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using `EF CodeFirst`, but if so, the following code may be useful for you:

```
    public class Human
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        private string insertedBy;

        public string InsertedBy
        {
            get { return insertedBy; }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(insertedBy))
                {
                    insertedBy = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

`InsertedBy` property won't be updated anymore.

Comment: This has the danger of if someone changes the value of InsertedBy during an update, it will overwrite the original InsertedBy.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich You can test it, it won't update the field because the former value in 'InsertedBy' is existed. I'm sure about that because I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I went by roundtripping the value of InsertBy. Read the value of InsertBy and update it with the same value.